# Problem with replacement rules

Tags: replacement, rule

I would like to apply substitution rules to an object I have defined, but I must be doing something wrong. Here are the relevant pieces of code. First I have defined a function `Vec` which is:

```
Vec[x_, y_String] := Subscript[Style[x, Italic, Bold], y]
```

Then I defined a function `Sprod` which is:

```
Sprod[x_String, y_String] := Vec[q, x]\[CenterDot]Vec[q, y]
```

Now I would like to apply the following substitution rule, for example:

```
Sprod["1", "2"] /. Sprod[i_String, j_String] -> whatever
```

However, when I do that, nothing happens. Does anyone have an idea of why?

I have tried the explicit rule

```
Sprod["1", "2"] /. Sprod["1", "2"] -> whatever
```

which works just fine. However, I'd like to write something a bit more general.

Comment: Just replace -> by :>, which is RuleDelayed[ ]

Comment: I tried, it but it still doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Since your have a definition Sprod[x_String, y_String] := Vec[q, x]\[CenterDot]Vec[q, y] after entering Sprod["1", "2"] your get Vec[q, "1"]\[CenterDot]Vec[q, "2"]. So, then there is nothing to replace. You can wrap expression with Hold: Hold[Sprod["1", "2"] ]/. Sprod[i_String, j_String] :> whatever  and then after replacement use ReleaseHold[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `Vec` and `Sprod` have restrictions on the heads of the arguments (namely to be strings), the lhs of the replacement doesn't evaluate because `i_String` has the `Pattern` head.

If we remove the head restrictions, it works just fine

```
Vec[x_, y_] := Subscript[Style[x, Italic, Bold], y]
Sprod[x_, y_] := Vec[q, x]\[CenterDot]Vec[q, y]
Sprod["1", "2"] /. Sprod[i_String, j_String] -> whatever
```

> whatever

Looking at the [`Trace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Trace.html) of the replacement shows

```
Sprod["1", "2"]
```

ends at

> Subscript[q, 1][CenterDot]Subscript[q, 2]

and

```
Sprod[i_String, j_String]
```

ends at

> Subscript[q, i_String][CenterDot]Subscript[q, j_String]

which yields a matching format/structure that can be replaced.

Instead of always using `Trace`, you can use [`MatchQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatchQ.html) in debugging replacement (or any pattern matching) issues.

With the original definitions

```
MatchQ[Sprod["1", "2"], Sprod[i_String, j_String]]
```

> False

and with the unrestricted definitions

```
MatchQ[Sprod["1", "2"], Sprod[i_String, j_String]]
```

> True